# Excel - Search value in row and then put a symbol to the the corresponding column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file looks like this:

```
ROW 1      1 2 3 4 
ROW 2      2 5 6 7 8
ROW 3      3 4 6 7 8
```

How can seach each row's cell value and then put a symble on the corresponding column? Sample Output:

```
Column Name 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 - I have this row now
ROW 1       * * * *
ROW 2         *     * * * *
ROW 3           * *   * * *
```

Is there any recommendations on how to achieve this or similar results?

**Updated:**
My initial data is Sheet1 A1 to AV450. The result should be show in Sheet2 A2 to EN 451. Sheet2 A1 to EN1 is a list of values that should be matched. Same sheet or not doesn't matter.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you trying to replace the values? Are you using a different Worksheet? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your initial rows are in Sheet1!A1 to F3

and your results in Sheet2!A1 to I4

put in cell Sheet2!B2 :

```
=if(not(iserror(match(B$1,Sheet1!A2:A3,0))),"*","")
```

Then you can extend the formula.

Match will return you the number of the cell in the searched matrix that contains the value, and "#NA" if the value is not found (thus is you don't want a "*" in the result)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I don't understand the match formula here.. initial rows are in Sheet1!A1 to AV450, results should in Sheet2 A2 to EN451, Sheet2 A1 to EN 1 is a list a values that should be matched. In my case, what should be the formula? I am so sorry that I didn't fully understand your formula...